# Fetching data from jdo datastore

Tags: java, gwt, serialization, jdo

I have created two classes on client-side and they are stored using GWT JDO.
The parent class looks like:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)  
public class Park implements Serializable{

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent
    private String parkId;  

    //...
    @Persistent(mappedBy = "park", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private List<Facility> facilityList;

    // other stuff
```

and the child looks like:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Facility implements Serializable{

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    private String encodedKey;

    @Persistent
    private Park park;

    // other stuff
```

And on server side, I have a method to fetch everything:

```
public Park[] getParks(){
    PersistentManager pm = getPersistentManager();
    ArrayList<Park> parkList = new ArrayList<Park>();
    try {
        Query q = pm.newQuery(Park.class);
        List<Park> parks = (List<Park>) q.execute();
        for(Park p:parks)
            parkList.add(p);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    return parkList.toArray(new Park[parkList.size()]);
}
```

When I call this method, it throws an exception:
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.backed.ArrayList' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.

I can't figure out whats wrong. Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a while back and it was quite frustrating. And I'm also quite sure your problem isn't because you imported the wrong package. You probably already solved this, but if anyone else need to solve the problem.

Try the below example code:

```
public Park[] getParks(){
    PersistentManager pm = getPersistentManager();
    List<Park> parkList = null;
    try {
        Query q = pm.newQuery(Park.class);
        parkList = (List<Park>) q.execute();
        parkList = pm.detachCopyAll(parkList);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    return parkList.toArray(new Park[parkList.size()]);
}
```

In the example above I've changed ArrayList to just List (not sure if necessary) and use detachCopyAll to copy the list so it is not connected to the datastore any more, this is the magic that removed the error for me.

There's an annotation that can be used, i quote from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata):

> You can modify an object after the PersistenceManager has been closed
>   by declaring the class as "detachable." To do this, add the detachable
>   attribute to the @PersistenceCapable annotation:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")
```

Not sure though if this means that you can do, what you originally did, but it's worth a try because I don't think my solution is "pretty".

Answer (score 0):

Change the `ArrayList` declaration to use Java's `ArrayList`:

```
   java.util.ArrayList<Park> parkList = new java.util.ArrayList<Park>();
```

`GWT` cannot serialize objects that do not have a default constructor and the `ArrayList` you have imported (org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.backed.ArrayList) doesn't provide a default constructor, making serialization fail.

It is possible that you imported this class by mistake  in which case you can just change the import declaration. But if you are using it somewhere else, then you will have to use the full qualifier as shown.